# How to fire onChange event for specific element in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi guys am new to react and after reading the doc. i jump straigth to developmentwith react, I have a set of elements with the fire the same onChange event now the problem i have is all the element are control rather than the targeted one

```
 function handleOnChange(e){
    let value = e.target.value
    if(isNaN(value)){
      value = 0
    }
    else if(value === "" || value <= 0){
      value = 0
    }
    setInfo(preInfo => {
      return{
        ...preInfo,
        quantity:value,
        
      }
    })
  }



 <div className="input-group buynum_select">
       <span className="input-group-btn">
       <button className="btn minus" 
         onClick={e => handlerUpdateQuantity(-1)}>-</button>
                            </span>
           <input maxLength="7" className="form-control" value={info.quantity} 
            onChange={e => handleOnChangeQuantity(e)}
            onKeyUp={e => handleKeyUpQuantity(e)} type="text"  
                   />
            <span className="input-group-btn">
             <button className="btn plus"
            onClick={e => handlerUpdateQuantity(1)}>+</button>
             </span>
        </div>

 <div className="input-group buynum_select">
       <span className="input-group-btn">
       <button className="btn minus" 
         onClick={e => handlerUpdateQuantity(-1)}>-</button>
                            </span>
           <input maxLength="7" className="form-control" value={info.quantity} 
            onChange={e => handleOnChangeQuantity(e)}
            onKeyUp={e => handleKeyUpQuantity(e)} type="text"  
                   />
            <span className="input-group-btn">
             <button className="btn plus"
            onClick={e => handlerUpdateQuantity(1)}>+</button>
             </span>
        </div>
```

I have multiple instance of the input field but when i try to change the value of input field one other input are updated as well . how can i target a specific input amoung others[image]

though i control only input 1 but input 2 also got value

Comment: As per your code, both controls are bind to same state i.e. `value={info.quantity}`

Comment: you can either abstract this into a separate element and keep separate state for each component OR you can use one state object with multiple keys for example value1: 1, value2: 5 etc...

Comment: @Dimitar Veljanovski the numbers of input field is dynamic so I wouldn't know how many value I would have.

Comment: You don't really need to know how many inputs you have, you can add as many properties to an object as you like, you just have to make them unique. Or just put the code for the quantity control into a separate component and keep the state for that component locally inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your two input fields has the same value with {info.quantity}.
You should change the value and the name to identify input control.

for example;

```
<input maxLength="7" className="form-control" name="quantity1" value={info.quantity1} 
            onChange={e => handleOnChangeQuantity(e)} />
<input maxLength="7" className="form-control" name="quantity2" value={info.quantity2} 
            onChange={e => handleOnChangeQuantity(e)} />
function handleOnChange(e){
    var name = e.target.name;
    var value = e.target.value;

    ...
    setInfo(preInfo => {
      return{
        ...preInfo,
        [name]:value,
        
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: is it possible to define info.quantity1 , info.quantity2 dynamic since i don't know how many of it i wold be needing. i used an object state

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to resolve this is to create a separate `counter` component which keeps its state locally:

```
const Counter = props => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  return (
    <div className="counter">
      <button onClick={e => setCount(count - 1)}> - </button>
      <input value={count} onChange={e => setCount(parseInt(e.target.value))} />
      <button onClick={e => setCount(count + 1)}> + </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This way, each component keeps different count.

I don't exactly know your use case but it might make more sense to utilize the same state as an object and keep each value under a specific property name of the object or keep an array as state and the Nth element in the array corresponds to the Nth count - `[3, 5, 1, 2, 0, 5]` means the first counter has the value 3, the second counter has value 5, the third has value 1 and so on... It all depends on the use case. If I was dynamically rendering each counter, I'd go with an array of values as it is most efficient in terms of memory and performance and a clean solution. If I have a fixed number of elements I'd probably go with a combination of object state and separate count component with setState passed down.

Comment: I think your second sugestion would be a solution, I want to track Item spec  for example color. I dont know how many color i wil hav for a perticular item but as many as it is i need to keep track of the qty of each color a user select. so i need an array as a state that can be dynamic, I think your second sugestion will do, but i don't know how to implement this.

Comment: how to implement using array of value as a state